# How do I amend this function so that it prints integers between 1 and its parameter, using a particular algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, for-loop, while-loop

I have been given the following exercise:

> Create a function "MyFunction" with 1 parameter, that will print
>   integers between 1 and its parameter, using a particular algorithm:
>
> ```
> MyFunction(25)
> 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25
>
> MyFunction(29)
> 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9, 13, 14, 15, 19, 20, 21, 25, 26, 27
> ```

I have managed to create a function which prints numbers between 1 and its parameter but how do I amend it to print that specific algorithm?

From my observation, it seems that for every 3 numbers it prints, it doesn't print the next 3 but I don't know how to write this in code. I have also tried to look online if there is some kind of formula or name of this algorithm which I can incorporate but haven't been successful.

```py
def my_function(n):
    for index in range(n):
        print (index + 1)

my_function(25)
my_function(29)
```

My code prints out integers between 1 and the parameter but I don't know how to print out the algorithm.

Also, side note: how do I use the code prettifier for future use?

Comment: Hi Welcome to StackOverflow aka. "SO"
Please see the help section as this will guide you in getting more support from us in the community.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/
Best wishes on your adventures! Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```py
def my_function(n):
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        print(i)
        if i % 3 == 0:
            i += 3
        i += 1
```

Basically, every time you were about to step into non-printable integers you just `jump over` them to the next printable one. As you have noticed, you always want to print 3 numbers and than don't print next 3 items. Version that makes this explicit could be coded as:

```py
def my_function(n):
    should_print = True
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        if should_print:
            print(i)
        if i % 3 == 0:
            should_print = not should_print
        i += 1
```

Expression `i % 3 == 0` is `True` every 3rd iteration which is exactly when we swap between printable and non-printable mode

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative solution

```
def my_function(n):
   for i in range(1, n + 1):
       if 0 < i % 6 <= 3:
          print(i)
```

Another less concise but more efficient solution is the following, where three numbers are printed each loop:

```
def my_function(n):
    i = -3
    for i in range(3, n + 1, 6):
        print(i - 2, i - 1, i, sep='\n')

    if i + 5 == n:
        print(n - 1, n, sep='\n')
    elif i + 4 == n:
        print(n)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! What does sep='\n' do?

Comment: Use the newline character (rather than the default space character) as the separator between numbers. You can try removing it and execute the program to see the difference.